# Responsive card layout with HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a card using [this media card code pen](https://codepen.io/Kelbin/pen/QWNzrjW) as reference. Here's what I want to do:

- I want to make the image fit the top half of my card and have the text below.
- I'm trying to add a card link that takes the user to another page, either by clicking on the title or anywhere on the card.

There's also an issue with the card layout:

- when I reduce the screen size, the right border gets covered like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB47b.png)

Edits: Fixed the issue with the above card layout. Added the heading before the card (it stretches outside the image container when the screen width is very small, not sure if that's a big issue) and improved some formatting (added media query, modified margin, height).

```css
/* Style the content-main heading */
.content-main {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px auto 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* for the rounded corners */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 1050px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.card-image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.card-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.card-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2E4053;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.card-text {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

/* Media query */
/* for navigation menu */
@media all and (max-width: 600px) { 
  ...
}
/* for cards */
@media query only screen and (max-width: 400px){
  .card-image {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- content-main heading -->
<div class="content-main">
  <h1>Navigation content</h1>
</div>

<!--Card contents-->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="/images/reviews-img-1.jpg" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="card-title">Reviews</a>
  <p class="card-text">
    This is the place for reviews on cameras and film.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="/images/resources-img-2.jpg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="card-title">Resources</a>
  <p class="card-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi rhoncus condimentum viverra.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="/images/wheretogetfilmdeveloped-img-3.jpg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="card-title">Where to Get Film Developed</a>
  <p class="card-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi rhoncus condimentum viverra.
  </p>
</div>
```

How do I create my card to make it similar to the code pen reference?

Comment: there referenced codepen is basically all you need :) 
for better understanding of responsiveness - check css-tricks web, there is full manual about this topic

Comment: yeah I've been referring to css-tricks - it's helpful but it gets a bit confusing sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `.card`

```
 max-width: 700px;
 max-height: 512px;
```

and add a class for `img`

```
.card-image img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Here is the result:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* for the rounded corners */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 512px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.card-image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.card-image img{
width:100%;
}
.card-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2E4053;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.card-text {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="https://dynaimage.cdn.cnn.com/cnn/c_fill,g_auto,w_1200,h_675,ar_16:9/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.cnn.com%2Fcnnnext%2Fdam%2Fassets%2F200424053232-tom-hanks-september-2019-file-restricted.jpg" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="card-title">Reviews</a>
  <p class="card-text">
    This is the place for reviews on cameras and film.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a media query for the card image at another breakpoint. Page looks ok when I test for some viewports. But my heading (before the card contents) overlaps the card when I reduce the width of the browser window, about 132px and lower

Comment: So update the question if I can I will help you, by the way is there any device with 132px or less?

Comment: Updated the question. And there isn't any screen size with a width of 132px or less, at least not on a typical device. I looked it up and the smallest screen size in active use is 320 pixels wide in the iPhone 5.

Comment: You said that you added media query but it isn't in you updated question. Tell me what's the problem exactly so I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Making images responsive can be tricky. I find using a div with the image as the background-image works well, see my modifications to your code below.  Not sure what you mean by responsive, you want an animation to occur when you click or hover? Or are you trying to link to something?

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* for the rounded corners */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Changes below */
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 512px;
  /* Changes above */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.card-image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* Changes below */
  background-image: url('/images/reviews-img-1.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Height should be the height of your photo - don't use a huge image size for a card component */
  height: 427px;
  width: 100%;
  /* Changes above */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .card-image {
    height: 300px;
  }
}

/* No changes to .card-title or .card-text */
```

```html
<!--Card contents-->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image"></div>
  <a href="#" class="card-title">Reviews</a>
  <p class="card-text">
    This is the place for reviews on cameras and film.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: by responsive, I mean make the card or its title link to another page containing other cards

Comment: Wrap it in an anchor tag, e.g. <a href="link-to-your-page"><h1>Title</h1></a>

Comment: ok. thanks :) also I already have a media query for the navigation menu - do I just wrap this code part in it?
      .card-image {
        height: 300px;
      }
    }

Comment: If you want the changes to be applied at the same breakpoint you could.  I actually think Ahmad's answer below is better than mine, so check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below snippet for image responsive as *width of card*, then **image** will *resize respectively*.

```css
/* Style the content-main heading */
.content-main {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* for the rounded corners */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.card-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.card-image img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.card-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2E4053;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
}
.card-text {
  margin: 0.65rem 0 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- content-main heading -->
<div class="content-main">
    <h1>Navigation content</h1>
</div>

<!--Card contents-->
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOGFG.png" alt="..." />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="card-title">Reviews</a>
    <p class="card-text">
        This is the place for reviews on cameras and film. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate veritatis asperiores harum officiis optio. Quis, repudiandae! Fuga ipsum laudantium omnis, dicta molestiae itaque aspernatur quam. Quam fugiat recusandae hic? Fugit.
    </p>
</div>
```